# Illegal instruction (core dumped) - When using an executable that works locally

Tags: ubuntu, executable

I have an issue trying to run an executable upon my Ubuntu server.

This executable ran perfectly upon the server less than 24 hours ago and still runs without an issue upon my local Ubuntu machine.

I ran ldd upon the program which returned this

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf76e1000)
libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4 => /srv/www/mods.tf/vpk/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4 (0xf769d000)
libtier0.so => /srv/www/mods.tf/vpk/libtier0.so (0xf7673000)
libvstdlib.so => /srv/www/mods.tf/vpk/libvstdlib.so (0xf7588000)
libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf7554000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf754f000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7469000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf744e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf72a7000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7289000)
librt.so.1 => /lib32/librt.so.1 (0xf7280000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76e2000)
```

Due to my running `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/srv/www/mods.tf/vpk:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which was needed for the above libraries to connect.

I was at work when the issue was first reported and it hasn't stopped since.

I downloaded the files in question to test them and they work perfectly.

I uploaded a differing version that I have which works to a differing location. No dice.

I would appreciate any and all help that can be thrown my way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my server, which was something I was hoping that I would not have to do.

This fixed the issue discussed above.

This implies to me that there may be an issue with the executable.

Comment: You should put things like this in as edits to your question, rather than answers.

Comment: Well, it answered the question. Sorry, I didn't make it clear that it fixed the issue.

Comment: Did it actually fix the issue, or will it come back in the future?

Comment: Unknown at this time. I believe it may return, but I shall see. If it returns before the weekend, I will not accept my answer.